# Is it possible to write full css line with LESSCSS using variables?

Tags: html, css, less

is there a way that you can write a full CSS line using a LESS variable?

For example, if I declare a variable:

`@dir: test;`

and then want that variable to be used within another variable:

`@bg-img: url(http://example.com/@dir/img/bg.png;`

When I try to use `@bg-img` in my CSS, it compiles like this:

`body{background-image:url(http://example.com/@dir/img/bg.png);`

How do I get `@dir` to echo out as `test`?

I know that I can just replace `@dir` but since I have various different microsites, it'll be quicker to change the one instance of `@dir` rather than go through and change every instance of the microsite name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by interpolation, but not certain if this would work in your particular situation without seeing more code. However, give this a try:

```
body{background-image:url(http://example.com/@{dir}/img/bg.png);
```

Found it in [the docs](http://lesscss.org/#-variables), down the page under String interpolation. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: and escape, just as @Rob W mentions in the comments. Also in the doc, just below interpolation.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much! Will make this accepted answer ASAP!

Comment: @BeatAlex Still outputs as `@{dir}` to me in LESS 1.4. You need to escape the value, as `@bg-img: ~"url(http://example.com/@{dir}/img/bg.png)"`.